# Couldn't get huge data using kendo dropdown virtualization

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am working on a project where around 3k-5k data will be loaded in the dropdown list.
So I decided to use `Kendo Dropdown Virtualization` and in the front end, I get data the way I want.
But I want to call the backend service each time after scrolling over `pageSize`.
Now my service loaded full data at once.

```
[valueField]="'value'"
[textField]="'text'"
[virtual]="{itemHeight: 30, pageSize: 50}"
[data]="theList"
```

Issues are:

**What is the alternative of valueMapper(Found it in jquery Docs) in angular?**

**How I set selected data from this huge list?**

**NB:** I am using the latest version of angular & kendo.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may want some sort of "Load more items" button next to the dropdownslist, or even append it to the `data` array so when the user selects it, you can load more data from your backend.

Comment: Not button actually. when I scrolling it will automatically hit backend and fetch more data after passing pagesize=50 numbers. Is it clear?